# dynamic int * arrays as key for C++ map

Tags: c++

I have some dynamic int * arrays that I would like to use as keys for an unordered_map.  I'm a bit unclear on how I should declare the key type so it would actually be the value of the entire array.

Also, to deallocate the memory for the arrays, do I use `map.clear()`?

Example:

```
unordered_map<??, int> frequency;

while (some_condition) {

  int *my_array = new int[size];
  putSomeValuesToArray(my_array);
  frequency[my_array]++;
}

// to deallocate memory for the arrays in frequency?
```

Comment: What's a "dynamic int * array"? A dynamic array of ints, or a dynamic array of int pointers, or an array of pointers to dynamic ints? Please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to stick `int*` as key inside a `std::map` and still be able to retrieve elements 'by value'. The reason for that is a single `int*` only provides the start of an array, you need the end too to compute anything (equivalently and more C-like, the length). In other words, `int*` does not an array (dynamic or otherwise) make; in this context it's an iterator to the start of a sequence.

You can use `std::pair<int*, int*>` but it should only be used for non-owning 'views' of data. That is, if you manually manage memory with a `std::map<std::pair<int*, int*>, int>` you'll end up with a headache. One possibility is using a smart-pointer: `std::pair<std::unique_ptr<int[]>, int*>`.  But as others have recommended, just use `std::vector` as it is still compatible with C-like interfaces that deal with `int*`. Plus a `const std::pair<std::unique_ptr<int>, int*>` still allows you to scribble the memory, which can mess up the ordering of the map and ends you up in trouble.

A final blow to using `int*` or `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` is that you would need to provide the strict weak ordering that `std::map` requires, whereas `std::vector<int>` comes with an appropriate `operator<`. On the other hand, you need to provide a hash for both if you settle instead on `std::unordered_map`. For what it's worth, a simple functor that uses `std::lexicographical_compare` (same semantics as `std::vector` comparison):

```
struct compare {
    typedef std::pair<std::unique_ptr<int[]>, int*> value_type;
    bool
    operator()(value_type const& lhs, value_type const& rhs) const
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.first.get(), lhs.second
                                           , rhs.first.get(), rhs.second);
    }
};
```

Then you can use `std::map<std::pair<std::unique_ptr<int[]>, int*>, int, compare>`.

Answer (score 4):

**Important:** If you use a dynamically allocated object in a STL Container, then to deallocate the memory you need to *walk* the container and call `delete` (or `delete[]`) explicitly.

I would strongly suggest moving from `int*` to `std::vector<int>`, you would not have the issue of memory ownership any longer then.

---

In order to declare a key, pass the type as the template parameter:

```
std::unordered_map<int*, Foo>
std::unordered_map<std::vector<int>, Foo>
```

Of course, for `unordered_map` you are likely going to need a specific `Hash` parameter, which derives a hash value from the `Key` you pass.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working with a lot pre-existing code that take these dynamic arrays as input.  So do you think I should just convert them to vectors in my own functions, or is there a more efficient way to work with them directly.  Also If i use int *, isn't that just the value of the first address in the array?

Comment: @wolve80: if a particular function takes a pointer to an array, and you have a vector, then you can pass it `&vector.front()`.

Comment: The advantage of using naked pointers as keys is that you don't need to think about hashing, and that they make for a fast key. You just have to be very careful when you erase elements from the map.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that how can I make the int * keys recognize the entire array value as the key.  In other words, if I have `array1 = {1,2,3} and array2 = {1,0,0}`, and if I use int * as keys, won't they compare the same?

Comment: @wolve No. They are different objects, so `array1 != array2` holds (remember we're doing pointer comparison here). Moreoever, if you want to retrieve an array that contains e.g. `{ 1, 2, 3 }` you can't do that without holding the original pointer that you put inside it. Creating a new dynamic array of `{ 1, 2, 3 }` will yield a different pointer. If that's not what you want, you need a custom hash.

Comment: @Luc, ah ok thanks.  Yes, what I need is if array1 = {1, 2, 3} and array2 = {1, 2, 3}, then they would be assigned the same key in the map.

Comment: @wolve: Do you want the map to be keyed on the *pointer* or on the *array*? Your question doesn't make that clear.

Comment: @Kerrek, sorry about the question being unclear. I have pre-existing int *arrays.  I want to use their values as keys for my map.

Comment: @wolve: If you want a range of values as a key, you should use something like the Boost range_hash, but you'll also have to provide equality comparison.

Comment: @wolve80: I strongly suggest you use `std::vector<int>`, unless the preexisting code may *modify* the size of the arrays you can pass `int*` by taking the address of the first element.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant,

```
int *p = new int[size];
```

and you want to make `p` as a key, then for you better choice will be to use `std::set()`.

Also, you cannot simply `clear()` it; you may want to `delete[]` each element before, to avoid memory leak. If you don't want to individually `delete[]` it then, you can use `shared_ptr` (or other [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)) which will do the job for you.

Comment: Why is std::set() a better choice?

Comment: @Dennis, because OP wants just the record of `int*` (pointer to dynamic array); and `find()` it whenever needed. OP doesn't really need any mapping. Thus `set()` is a good choice here.

Comment: Yes I guess just adding to the set and using `count` would work.